# Jacobi fields on non-geodesic curves

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

The point of Jacobi fields is to study variations of geodesics through geodesics, but the Jacobi equation $D_t^2 J + R(J,\dot\gamma)\dot\gamma=0$ makes sense for any curve $\gamma$, not just for geodesics.

Are solutions to this equation still interesting in other situations? For instance, does a variation of a curve along a "Jacobi field" yield curves with related geodesic curvatures? Maybe this is related to e.g. curve shortening flow or some other already studied notions.

Comment: Interesting... One would expect the Jacobi equation to make no sense for non-geodesic $\gamma$ since it comes from the second variation of Energy and usually it doesn't make any sense to consider second derivatives at non-critical points.

Comment: @CarlosEsparza: Of course there is a metric running around on the path space (say of paths of Sobolev class $H^1$), hence one can define the second derivative everywhere.

Comment: In the two-dimensional case, variation of a curve along such a Jacobi field yield curves with the same geodesic curvatures.
(It is an application of Gauss--Bonnet.)